# MFC resources / links

Tags: c++, c, mfc

I am about to reenter the MFC world after years away for a new job. What resources to people recommend for refreshing the memory? I have been doing mainly C# recently.

Also any MFC centric websites or blogs that people recommend?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- For blogs: Your best bet would be the [Visual C++ Team Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/vcblog/default.aspx).
- For books: [Programming Windows with MFC](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1572316950) is one of the best book on the subject.
- For tutorials: Simply [search google for various tutorials on MFC](http://www.google.ca/search?q=mfc+tutorial&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a).

[image]

Answer (score 7):

The best: [The Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/)

Comment: Back in the day when I used MFC for alot of my work I used Code Project as my reference point. good call

Answer (score 3):

I would highly recommend my all-time favorite book: [*MFC Internals: Inside the Microsoft© Foundation Class Architecture*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201407213)

**It is not a 'how-to' book — it is a 'how does it work' book.**

[image]

Answer (score 3):

There's lots of useful information here:

http://www.flounder.com/mvp_tips.htm

Answer (score 2):

Its been a long time since i did any MFC but back then it used to be

"MFC internals" + debug into the MFC code and find what happens which used to be the best resources on MFC

Samples used to be available from Code Project to quickly get you going.

Answer (score 1):

The vital "how do I?" book is [http://www.amazon.com/gp/reader/0201185377/ref=sib_dp_pt#reader-link](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201185377)

Codeproject is also invaluable, although many of the 3rd party controls there nowhave counterparts in the new MFC feature pack.

Answer (score 0):

Books are one thing, but I always found that practice was the key with MFC. [CodeGuru](http://www.codeguru.com) was my favourite destination to answer anything MFC-related.

There's also that new website. What's it called...that's it - [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/)!