# how to start c++ mfc application

Tags: c++, mfc

i work last 3 years on c#. now for some reason i have to make some MFC cpp application.
so what u people suggest for me. is it harder then c#? how can i begin? in c# i started just making some puzzle game do i follow the same for it? what is the best way to learn MFC c++? where i can find the resource?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MFC does not really hide the fact that it is built upen the Win32 API. So, the answer to your question really depends on whether you have been exposed to this API and if so how familiar you are with it.

When I used to program MFC (those were the days...) it really helped me understand to create an application *without* any help of any wizard. That is obviously not to say, that I wouldn't ever suggest using the wizard.

The book I used to learn MFC was *Programming Windows with MFC* by Jeff Prosise.

The Scrible Tutorial, currently at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa716527%28VS.60%29.aspx is not bad, either.

Also check this thread: [MFC resources / links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27779/mfc-resources-links) .

Answer (score 1):

MFC and C++ are harder than C#. It's very powerful but has a learning curve.

I would suggest you read the documentation on "Model/View Architecture" then use the wizard in visual studio to create an example application to use as a model.

Comment: thank u, there are lot of option in vs2010 to create a mfc a1pplication, these r just freaking me out. but cant deny its interesting than c#, i just searching for perfect tutorial or suggestion to pick up a line for fast learning.