# Getting a compilation error in VS2010 by following the first hello world example

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, mfc, compiler-errors, visual-c++-2010

i just started learning MFC..found a tutorial here http://bit.ly/j2uhHO ..just tried the same thing in VS2010 but getting a compilation error in this code..

```
void CChildView::OnPaint() 
{

    CPaintDC dc(this); // device context for painting

    dc.TextOut(0, 0, "Hello, world!");

    // TODO: Add your message handler code here

    // Do not call CWnd::OnPaint() for painting messages
}
```

And the error is:

`error C2664: 'BOOL CDC::TextOutW(int,int,const CString &)' : cannot convert parameter 3 from 'const char [14]' to 'const CString &`'

Can anyone solve this and suggest some mfc tutorials please..thank u..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error tells you whats exactly wrong.

```
error C2664: 'BOOL CDC::TextOutW(int,int,const CString &)' : cannot convert parameter 3 from 'const char [14]' to 'const CString &'
```

`TextOutW()` is expecting `const CString &` as the third parameter and you are passing `const char [14]`

You need to do:

```
dc.TextOut(0, 0, L"Hello, world!");
```

Which passes the third argument in the format desired by the function.

For MFC resources to refer, you see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27779/mfc-resources-links).

Comment: Thank u very much..can u suggest me some good MFC tutorials for beginers beginners

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that Windows by default uses wide characters `wchar_t` for texts. You would need

```
    dc.TextOut(0, 0, L"Hello, world!");
```