# Programming with Microsoft Visual C++ MFC 2021

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2017, mfc, visual-studio-2019

Many years ago I learned Visual C++ MFC with these books for Visual C++ 6.0 and Visual C++ .NET 2003 respectively by George Shepherd and David Kruglinski:

[image: Programming with Microsoft Visual C++ .Net, Fifth Edition]
[image: Programming with Microsoft Visual C++ .Net, Sixth Edition]

But now I don't find some last edition with Visual C++ 2017 o Visual C++ 2019, MFC is discontinued and obsolete?

Thanks.

Comment: There isn't much investment into MFC from Microsoft. It's still the only supported framework for native code, and it does see updates. As with anything native things change at a much slower rate, so the old books are still mostly relevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According with the comment from @IInspectable we can say that MFC mainly remained the same across these years (but some new features and changes have been added - for example - *MFC Feature Pack*), but good old books

[image: Programming Windows with MFC, By J.Prosise]
[Programming Windows with MFC, By J.Prosise](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1572316950)

[image: Programming Microsoft Visual C++, By D. Kruglinksky]
[Programming Microsoft Visual C++, By D. Kruglinksky](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01F7XD2MC)

are still good and not obsolete.

But there are some "new" (more or less) books that also cover MFC Feature Pack, for example:
[image: Beginning Visual C++ 2012, by Ivor Horton]
[Beginning Visual C++ 2012, by Ivor Horton](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1118368088)

[image: Beginning Visual C++ 2013, by Ivor Horton]
[Beginning Visual C++ 2013, By Ivor Horton](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00JNOJVJK)

Also here is a [list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27779/mfc-resources-links) as StackOverflow's answer of MFC resources. (But they are not dynamically changed). (Maybe, they will be useful for you).

But "traditional" books from J.Prosise and D.Kruglinsky are sufficient in most cases, at least for a system view on the subject.

Comment: One of the biggest changes too was the resizing of controls using dynamic layouts.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle Good point. Another big improvement was on Feature Pach in 2008 with Feature Pack: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/mfc-update-powered-by-bcgsoft/

Comment: Thank you very much, I have been doing many C# recently and I want to refresh my knowledge in C++ MFC.